# sort Arraylist<String> to merge lines with the same name at the beging

Tags: java

I am parsing pdf time table to create JSON file I have alle string in the text document in an arrayList. I want to join the lines in the text document  with the same stop Name. Is there any help class in Java to do that?

**Simple:**

```
amsterdam street 04:41 05:41 06:09 06:38 07:08 07:38 08:08 08:38 09:08 09:38 10:08 10:38 11:08 11:38
paris  04:43 05:43 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 08:41 09:11 09:41 10:11 10:41 11:11 11:41
rom  04:48 05:48 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46 08:16 08:46 09:16 09:46 10:16 10:46 11:16 11:46
amsterdam street 12:08 12:38 13:08 13:38 14:08 14:38 15:08 15:38 16:08 16:38 17:08 17:38 18:08 18:38
paris  12:11 12:41 13:11 13:41 14:11 14:41 15:11 15:41 16:11 16:41 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41
rom  12:16 12:46 13:16 13:46 14:16 14:46 15:16 15:46 16:16 16:46 17:16 17:46 18:16 18:46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work we have to make some assumptions, because there is no safe delimiter. So we have to find the strongest indicator to where to split off the head. It looks like a line always ends with times in the `hh24:mm` format. We could use this information:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = 
    Pattern.compile("^ *(.+?)((?: +(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])+) *$");

public static final void splitLine(String line) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("stop: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("times: " + matcher.group(2));
        // the time string will have the space(s) at the beginning, so it can be
        // concatenated without problem, but the first space might have to be trimmed
    }
}
```

(Tested.) The merging isn't too difficult any more (untested):

```
// adaptation of splitLine(), just iterate through all lines, then you will have
// everything in the map and you can iterate over the entry sets.
private void addLine(String line, Map<String, String> stops) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        if (stops.containsKey(matcher.group(1))) {
            stops.put(matcher.group(1), stops.get(matcher.group(1)) + matcher.group(2));
        } else {
            stops.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2).trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do the merge but when I declare the map and add the following  replace the both lines with ` times.get(matcher.group(1)).append(matcher.group(2));` I am getting this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`  Can you please add the merging code to your answer to test it?

Comment: @MrPencil check it now.

Comment: Declare and initialize it in the method parsing the ArrayList, use HashMap. It is a Map<Stop, Times> (both Strings of course)

Comment: But I am getting noe another error `The method hasKey(String) is undefined for the type Map<String,String>` ? at `hasKey, push ` lines?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html containsKey

Comment: I did, this is the Java API, you should always work with the API... nobody can know every single detail by heart.

Comment: when you use Stringbuilder you need to concatenate with append and not with + ... I'm sorry, but this is not: *implement this for free*, it is *ask a specific question, get a response*... you still have to write the program yourself.

Comment: I can uderstand your point sir it works now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have all of the lines in an `ArrayList<String>`, and you need to join lines that start with the same two words. I would first split on the space character, then merge lines that start with the same thing. I like using `Map`s in this case, because it's easy to stay organized.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s*((?:\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2})+)");

// A map will keep us organized, because it disallows duplicate keys
Map<String, StringBuilder > times = new HashMap<>(); // Map<header, times>
for (String line : LINES_IN_FILE) {
    // Separate the times from the header and each other
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(line);

    // Use the first capturing group as the key and the second as the value
    times.get(match.group(1)).append(match.group(2));
}

// now for some post-processing
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>(times.keySet().size());
for (String key : times.keySet()) {
    result.add(key + " " + times.get(key);
}
return result;
```

Comment: Your split would fail, if the name of the stop is not exactly two words. In the examples it always is, so maybe as a question to the OP: Are your stop names always exactly two words separated by space?

Comment: I assumed it would be, as I had no reason to believe otherwise. Certainly if it's true, the problem is simplified. Otherwise, I might use regular expressions to distinguish time-formatted strings from vanilla ones.

Comment: @Grmpfhmbl  yes you are right the stop Name is not always two words.

Comment: @gobernador sorry for my mistake

Comment: So I'd then more like use a regex instead of split(). Eg. (.*)\s+(\d\d:\d\d)+ the first capturing group would be your stop, the latter would give you the times

Comment: @Grmpfhmbl I used both, using a regex to match the split strings.

Comment: @gobernator: I'd for readability of the code, not try to split and then rejoin, but to split away the header. But that might just be a matter of taste and as I just saw, my regex was rubbish :-) Must be more like (.*?)\s*((?:\s\d\d:\d\d)+)

Comment: @Grmpfhmbl You're right, that's much more readable.

Comment: ham I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`!?